# What is the week number of a week with a weekday(of day X) in a month of a given day X?

Tags: dart

I'm looking for a way to get the week number of a week with a weekday(of day X) in a month of day X.

For example:- What is the week number of the week with weekday Tuesday in it of day 13? Answer - second.
[Image of the April month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKRD7.jpg)

I know it sounds confusing so here's example 2 - If I provide a date of 24 May 2021 then I would like to know that it is the fourth Monday of the month.
[Image of the May month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7tSZ.jpg)

I would be happy with a general answer but it would be great to know if there's an efficient way to do that using dart. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple math. Get the day of week. Get the day of month, subtract 1, and integer divide by 7, and add 1. Now you have "Monday" "4th one of the month".

To explain, think about it.  Days numbered 1 to 7 are *always* the first one of those days in the month.  Similarly, days numbered 8 to 14 are *always* the second one of those days in the month.  Quick math shows that you want:

```
(dayOfMonth - 1) ~/ 7 + 1
```

and for dayOfWeek, 1 Jan 1970 was a thursday, and here's some code:

```
void main() {
  var epoch = DateTime.utc(1970, 1, 1);
  var target = DateTime.utc(2021, 5, 24); // your input goes here
  var days = (target.difference(epoch)).inDays;
   // epoch is thursday, so we count back to following sunday
  days -= 3;
  var dow = days % 7;
  print(dow); // sunday = 0 ... saturday = 6
}
```

This prints "1" in dartpad.  Monday!

Be sure to use utc, or you can get messed up on DST.

Comment: Very nice solution . But I didn't understand what you meant by this line "Be sure to use UTC, or you can get messed up on DST.". So, can you please explain it a bit more? Thank you very much.

Comment: I also didn't understand that why we had to subtract 1, and integer divide by 7 and add 1 to get the week number. And I also did not understand why we did 
`
days -= 3;
var dow = days % 7; 
`
in finding dayOfWeek. 
I did understand that we are taking epoch as a reference and then finding the difference between epoch and target in days but I didn't get the rest of it. So it would be very helpful if you can explain them also. Thank you.

Comment: For the week of month, the function I gave does the right thing for every number from 1 to 31 (or even 300 if we had that many days in a month :).  epoch is a thursday.  I needed to make sunday be 0 mod 7 days, so I subtract 3.  Friday, Saturday, Sunday.

Comment: And local time (but not utc) has DST, which means the time delta when you cross a DST boundary is off by an hour one way or the other.  Always always do your storage and computations in utc.  For example, in the northern hemisphere, *most* of the northern hemisphere moved forward an hour at 2am (or so) this morning.  Thus midnight today to midnight tomorrow is 23 hours, not 24 hours, and you'll get a wrong value for .inDays, which will be 0 instead of 1.  With utc, you don't have that problem, since utc never has 23 hour or 25 hour days!

Comment: Ahh... I just found DateTime.weekday!  it returns 1..7 (monday through sunday), not 0..6 (sunday through saturday), but seems usable otherwise.  And I'll be doing a screencast shortly that shows the problem of the 25 hour day in date arithmetic.